# How to bind a context menu to a listbox item's button in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listbox, contextmenu

I'm trying to bind a context menu to a listbox and have it open when the user clicks on a button inside the listbox item.
If I apply the context menu to the listbox itself, bindings work correctly.
If I apply the context menu to the button inside the listboxitem I am unable to have it bound to the listbox item data context.

Therefore, the following works, but only right clicking on the listbox item:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
            <MenuItem
                Header="{Binding Name}"
                IsCheckable="True"
                IsChecked="{Binding Active}" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </ListBox.ContextMenu>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <RadioButto />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

In the following one I'm trying to bind the context menu from under the radio button so that later I can open the context menu by left clicking on the button rather than right clicking anywhere in the listbox item:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"> 
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext}">
                            <MenuItem
                                Header="{Binding Name}"
                                IsCheckable="True"
                                IsChecked="{Binding Active}" />
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </RadioButton.ContextMenu>
                </RadioButton>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I tried various Binding options but didn't have much luck.

Any solution that gets me the context menu next to the button when I click on the button (and on the button only) would do.

Comment: Based on your code, it seems that Context menu of Button would be opened here on right click . If you wan to open the context menu on left click on Button then the code should be written. Here, either you can use `EventTrigger -> StoryBoard` or `Interactivity` Triggers

Comment: Sure, but my problem is binding the data context here. Not the left vs right click.

Comment: Do you see any binding error in output window when you are debugging?

Comment: System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext; DataItem=null; target element is 'ContextMenu' (Name=''); target property is 'DataContext' (type 'Object')

Comment: Try setting the Context Menu data context as `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=DataContext}"`

Comment: This way, on the other hand, works:
<RadioButton Tag="{Binding .}">
and <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

Comment: With the suggested FindAncestor I still get errors: System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext; DataItem=null; target element is 'ContextMenu' (Name=''); target property is 'DataContext' (type 'Object')

Comment: I'll take the shortcut and go with the Tag binding for now...

Comment: Why are you setting the DataContext at all? Don't you want to bind to the Active and Name properties of the current item?